# Firebase: Setting up different environments for Auth and Notification

Tags: java, android, ios, firebase, flutter

I have 2 mobile apps and one web app which use the same Firebase Auth and Notification services. I only use Auth and Notification services, nothing else.

I require to have a staging environment and production environment, and both need to run in parallel.

I do not see other option in Firebase rather than creating two different projects. But that's risky, because I have to replace the JSON files in mobile app, replace Admin SDK stuff in web app and so on.

So what's the best option for this? I use Firebase only for Auth and Notification. In notification I send messages to individual devices and user groups.

maybe asking the users to use different email accounts for testing and production is the way to go? (Because then the Auth data will not be messed up even though the same Auth space is used)

Answer (score 0):

You could have only one single Firebase project and inside this project create several apps. For instance, you could create an app for production with the package name(android)/bundle id(iOS) "com.example.myapp" and another for staging "com.example.myapp.staging". That way, you can download a single json file with both configurations. In your android studio/xcode, you have to set up those package name/bundle id with the corresponding build configuration.

Comment: I know I can create multiple apps. That's not my question. My question is  regardless how many apps I create inside a project, I have a single Auth system and Notification system. All apps inside a single project will use them by default, because that's how Firebase works.

Also I don't think having stage/prod  package names is the way to go.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments

Comment: So if I do it like that, I am going to get two different copies of Auth section? For an example, the list of email / password collected in production will be separate from the email / password collected in staging? Or both will be available in the same Auth section? (Which means, the user in "staging" can log into the production app as well, because his Authentications are saved)

Comment: Because as I mentioned, I only use Firebase for authentication and notification. I don't use it for database purposes. So I'm looking for a solution where I can staging/prod environments for Authentication. Then I will have 2 different copies of Authentication.

Comment: As the documentation said, you could have 2 projects in firebase (production and staging), each one with its own authentication and notification system. They will generate 2 json/plist files that you have to add to your android/iOS project and configure them to associate each file with a build variant (android) or target (iOS). That way, your users will belong just to the firebase project where they sign up.

Comment: @PeakGen Hi! How did you solve this issue?